# havaing error in jpql query

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0, jpql

```
public List<SchoolDTO> getSchoolList() throws FortuneEnterpriseException {
        List<School> listSchools=new ArrayList<School>();
        List<SchoolDTO> dto = null;
        SchoolMapper sMapper =new SchoolMapper();
        try{

            Query query=entityManager.createNamedQuery("SELECT e FROM School e");
            listSchools=query.getResultList();
            dto= new ArrayList<SchoolDTO>();
            for (School school : listSchools) {
                dto.add(sMapper.mapToDTO(school));
            }
            return dto;
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw new FortuneEnterpriseException("appplication.error");
            }

        }
```

Error: 13:15:01,845 ERROR [stderr] (default task-21) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [SELECT e FROM School e]

```
Tell me my mistake.
```

Comment: You are using worng create method, createNamedQuery is for named query, use createQuery! It's a common autocompletition error!!

Answer (score 0):

this line is wrong:

```
Query query=entityManager.createNamedQuery("SELECT e FROM School e");
```

should be:

```
Query query=entityManager.createQuery("SELECT e FROM School e");
```